# C# - Can't install SQLite System.Data.SQLite

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I started learning C# a week ago. Today I was trying to install the System.Data.SQLite plugin or whatever that is from this page of the [SQLite offical website](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).
But after I installed it I couldn't see it in:
Project->Add Reference->.NET[tab].
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I really need to make the integration with SQLite for my application.
Thanks a lot.

---

Best Regards,
Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During setup, have you ticked the checkbox that said something like "Install assemblies into global assembly cache"? I believe it is unchecked by default.
Try referencing the library using the Browse tab instead if you can't find it in the GAC.

Comment: I think that I checked it, but anyway I think it worked now. Thanks.